# What should a microsoft shop use for Authentication and Authorization for the Web

Tags: authentication, authorization

I work in a decent sized enterprise shop and we have previously been using CA Siteminder for Authentication and Authorization of our web based users. It's a good product and is a candidate as we move forward, but we need to look at alternatives. As a Microsoft shop we usually like to look at the product that Microsoft has available, but I realised that Microsoft does not really have an equivalent product. Or am I missing something?

I could use Active directory but is that really a good choice? It does not seem like that was what it was intended for.

I could use ASP.NET providers and although it is easy to work with, it is not very full featured and is a little home grown, for security software, a trusted vender is appealing.

So what should I use?

Comment: Without knowing what your applications' needs are for authentication and authorization, there's no way to suggest anything. There are a _wide_ variety of needs and lots of different solutions that meet them in different ways.

Answer (score 0):

Wow seriously disappointing response. 
For any others that are curious about what we have chosen to do, at this point we are going down the path of using Forms Authentication with a SQL server backend. CA Siteminder is too expensive, and we don't have enough experience with LDAP and active directory to feel confident about using it as a provider even though most commercial products seem to use this (LDAP) technology